# Primeng- Angular2 - Dropdown in p-dataTable has styling issue

Tags: angular

I am using primeng datatable and applied a dropdown in it. Everything works properly except when the dropdown is populated I cannot open the dropdown by mouse but I can change the selected item, by Keyboard.
I have attached the image from my UI.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="sites" [(selection)]="selectedSites" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" (onRowUnselect)="onRowUnselect($event)">
            <p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
            <p-column field="siteName" header="{{'SITE_FORM.SITENAME' | translate}}" sortable="true"></p-column>
            <p-column field="clientName" header="{{'SITE_FORM.CLIENTNAME' | translate}}" sortable="true"></p-column>
            <p-column header= "{{ 'ROLE_FORM.NAME' | translate }}">
                <template let-site="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
                    <p-dropdown [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [options]="site.rolesSelectItem" [(ngModel)]="site.selectedRole"></p-dropdown>
                </template>                  
            </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

[UI result in my local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIxbY.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Try;

```
<p-dropdown appendTo="body"
```

Comment: Interesting, it worked for me. Alternative is http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=46449&start=10#p147984

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I added the Theme from ngPrime site and it is working now but it is overriding our own theme and I am not sure if I just grab the styling from the dropdowns and add it to our style.less